# Can not send data through Socket after Remote device turned off

Tags: c#, sockets, printing

I'm sending data to printer, I have my socket defined on my printer object in order to close socket after each instance, but when I turn my printer off and turn it back on again my service doesn't pick it up except if I restart my service, I wanted when I turn my printer off my service finds it's way to print again without restarting the service.

```
    public class printerObject
{
    public SocketTCPClient tcpSocket;
    public string printerIP;
    public string printerName;
    string dataBuffer;

    public void initializing(string Data)
    {
        dataBuffer = Data;
        if (tcpSocket==null)
        {
            tcpSocket = new clsSocketTCPClient();
            tcpSocket.tcpSocketEvent += tcpSocket_tcpSocketEvent;
            tcpSocket.ReceiveTerminator = "\r\n";
            tcpSocket.SendTerminator = "\r\n";
        }

        //Check if data in buffer
        if (dataBuffer.Length == 0)
            return;

        //Connect to printer
        tcpSocket.Connect(printerIP, portNumber);
        Cosole.WriteLine("Connected")
    }

    private void tcpSocket_tcpSocketEvent(int ClientHandle, SocketTCPClient.EventCodes EventCode, string Data)
    {
        //Send data, once confirm connected
        switch (EventCode)
        {
            //case CONNECTED:
            case SocketTCPClient.EventCodes.Status_Connected:
                tcpSocket.SendData(dataBuffer);
                break;

            case SocketTCPClient.EventCodes.Status_DataSent:
                dataBuffer = "";
                tcpSocket.CloseSocket();
                break;

            case SocketTCPClient.EventCodes.Status_Disconnect:
                    break;
            case SocketTCPClient.EventCodes.Error_Receiving:
                    break;
            case SocketTCPClient.EventCodes.Error_Sending:
                    break;
            case SocketTCPClient.EventCodes.Error_Connect:
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about calling "tcpSocket.Connect(..." again ? If your printer is off, your tcpSocket will never know it, unless you send/read something to it.

Comment: the socket turned off everytime I send data and it turns back on when the object required

Comment: _"my service doesn't pick it up"_ -- what does "doesn't pick it up" mean, _precisely_? State in clear, unambiguously descriptive terms _exactly_ what happens to your service, the PC, etc. Note that this likely has little to do with sockets, especially on the C# side; in a well-behaved network, a lost connection will be detected the next time you try to send data to the connection.

Comment: If your printer is accepting network packets destined for a connection that no longer exists (because the printer was off then back on again), rather than rejecting them, there's not much you're going to be able to do about that, other than get the printer manufacturer to provide a firmware upgrade that fixes their bug.